# Django 2.1 : Render JSONresponse to template, byte string doesn't work with javascript

Tags: json, django, python-3.x

In view:

```
response = JsonResponse(available_lessons, safe=False)
```

In template:

```
var available_lessons_json = {{available_lessons_json.content|safe}}
```

In my source js file I see:

```
var available_lessons_json = b'{"courses": {"courseName": "Everyday English", "lessons": ["Phrasal Verbs I", "Phrasal Verbs II", "Phrasal Verbs III"]}}'
```

which is giving me the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render your template with your data, your should use `render` function not `JsonResponse`. This should be like this.

```
return render(request, template, {'available_lessons': available_lessons})
```

In your template

```
var available_lessons_json = {{available_lessons|safe}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't like the `b` at the start of your response content, which denotes that it is a byte string. `response.content` always encodes to bytes- which you can decode with `{{available_lessons_json.content.decode|safe}}`

Just be aware that if `response.content` contains user input you're likely to be introducing [XSS vulnerabilities into your site](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17419#comment:27)